# Override Form Restore from Taskbar

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, taskbar

Can I override Form Restore function from task bar?
Actually I want to Override the function that causes a form to restore when clicked from task bar. I tried to override wndproc() and form_activated(), but of no use. Kindly help me solving my problem

Comment: Can you clarify - is this VB6 or VB.NET?  Two completely different technologies.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple code to restore the form and show back from the taskbar.

```
Me.WindowState = vbNormal
```

If you want to try, create a new timer, set interval to 3000 and write this code

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Me.WindowState = vbNormal
    End Sub
```

And run it, and immidiately minimize your window. Then wait for 2 or 3 seconds... :) 
is that Appearing?
Thank you.